# Null Pointer Exception using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a null pointer exception trying get a new activity to start when the user chooses a different locale. It seems to be occuring in the intent line as marked. (I'm a noob so simple explanations please!)
Thanks

```
public void changeLocale(String locale){
    try{
    String l=locale;
     if(l.equals("uk")){
        this.isUk=true;
        Log.i(Log_tag,"isUk is true");
        //Toast.makeText(this, "UK region selected in Prefs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Prefs.this, UK.class);//<---ERROR IS OCCURING HERE
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if(l.equals("eu")){
        this.isEu=true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "EU region selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Prefs.this, EU.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if(l.equals("us")){
        this.isUs=true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Us region selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Prefs.this, US.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if (l.equals("")){
        Log.i(Log_tag,"no locale passed in");
        finish();
    }
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        Log.i(Log_tag, "Null Pointer Error in changeLocale()"+e);
        finish();
    }
}
```

My logcat says this:

```
05-25 11:55:57.851: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(898): No keyboard for id 0
05-25 11:55:57.861: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(898): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

05-25 11:56:01.522: INFO/(898): UK selected in UsFM
05-25 11:56:01.543: INFO/(898): editRegion() started
05-25 11:56:01.642: INFO/(898): isUk is true
05-25 11:56:01.642: INFO/(898): Null Pointer Error in changeLocale()java.lang.NullPointerException

05-25 11:56:01.953: INFO/NotificationService(69): enqueueToast pkg=com.silifeform.android callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@4380ba08 duration=0
05-25 11:56:01.995: INFO/ActivityManager(69): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.silifeform.android/.Us }

05-25 11:56:02.182: WARN/InputManagerService(69): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@438d8b88 (uid=10024 pid=898)
```

The whole class looks like this:

```
package com.silifeform.android;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Prefs extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME="LocalePrefs";
    private String region;
    public boolean isUk;
    public boolean isUs;
    public boolean isEu;
    private String Log_tag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);

        //restore prefs
        SharedPreferences settings= getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
        String myRegion = settings.getString(region,"us");

        this.region=myRegion;
        changeLocale(getRegion(this));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        changeLocale(getRegion(this));
    }

    public void editRegion(Context cxt, String sregion) {
        setRegion(sregion);
        Log.i(Log_tag,"editRegion() started");
        SharedPreferences settings = cxt.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = settings.edit();
        ed.clear();
        ed.putString(this.region,sregion);
        ed.commit();
        changeLocale(sregion);
    }

    public String getRegion(Context cxt){
            SharedPreferences settings= cxt.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
            String myRegion = settings.getString(this.region,"us");
            return myRegion;
        }

    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }


    public void changeLocale(String locale){
        try{
        String l=locale;
         if(l.equals("uk")){
            this.isUk=true;
            Log.i(Log_tag,"isUk is true");
            Log.i(Log_tag,l);
            //Toast.makeText(this, "UK region selected in Prefs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Prefs.this, UkFuelMoney.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(l.equals("eu")){
            this.isEu=true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "EU region selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Prefs.this, EuFuelMoney.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(l.equals("us")){
            this.isUs=true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Us region D selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Prefs.this, UsFuelMoney.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if (l.equals("")){
            Log.i(Log_tag,"no locale passed in");
            finish();
        }
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            Log.i(Log_tag, "Null Pointer Error in changeLocale()"+e);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = settings.edit();
        ed.putString(region,region);
        ed.commit();

    }
}
```

Thanks Keno. The stack trace looks like this:

```
05-25 12:10:44.162: WARN/System.err(961): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 12:10:44.172: WARN/System.err(961):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
05-25 12:10:44.182: WARN/System.err(961):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
05-25 12:10:44.182: WARN/System.err(961):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2302)
05-25 12:10:44.182: WARN/System.err(961):     at com.silifeform.android.Prefs.changeLocale(Prefs.java:68)
05-25 12:10:44.192: WARN/System.err(961):     at com.silifeform.android.Prefs.editRegion(Prefs.java:46)
05-25 12:10:44.192: WARN/System.err(961):     at com.silifeform.android.Us.onOptionsItemSelected(Us.java:347)
05-25 12:10:44.192: WARN/System.err(961):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2096)
05-25 12:10:44.202: WARN/System.err(961):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:825)
05-25 12:10:44.202: WARN/System.err(961):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:139)
05-25 12:10:44.202: WARN/System.err(961):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:813)
05-25 12:10:44.202: WARN/System.err(961):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:120)
05-25 12:10:44.212: WARN/System.err(961):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:884)
05-25 12:10:44.212: WARN/System.err(961):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
05-25 12:10:44.212: WARN/System.err(961):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3246)
05-25 12:10:44.222: WARN/System.err(961):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1635)
05-25 12:10:44.222: WARN/System.err(961):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-25 12:10:44.222: WARN/System.err(961):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-25 12:10:44.232: WARN/System.err(961):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-25 12:10:44.232: WARN/System.err(961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
05-25 12:10:44.242: WARN/System.err(961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 12:10:44.242: WARN/System.err(961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-25 12:10:44.242: WARN/System.err(961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
05-25 12:10:44.252: WARN/System.err(961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
05-25 12:10:44.252: WARN/System.err(961):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 12:10:44.252: INFO/(961): Null Pointer Error in changeLocale()java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: What's `Prefs` and is it, or `Prefs.this` null?

Comment: just print "l" to console & check what u r getting in it & also put u r log

Comment: Prefs is the class. I was wondering about that. My understanding is that the intent takes the activity where you are now and the activity you want to start, is that right?

Comment: Could you show snippet of code you have written for changeLocale?

Comment: l is coming back as "uk" as intended.

Comment: In your catch block, do a e.printStackTrace() to see exactly where the null is originating from. Will be easier to track that way.

Comment: Seems its my current nemesis Context again. Can anyone help with what I need to do with this?

Comment: have u registered ur acivtivities in ur manifest file???

Answer (score 1):

Your `Prefs` Activity is not populated as you probably have instantiated it yourself in `com.silifeform.android.Us.onOptionsItemSelected()` (I guess the implementation is still similar to the one you posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991289/sharedpreferences-null-pointer-exception)). As I already pointed out in reply to th referred question of you, if the `Prefs` class is not instantiated (and managed) by Android, you cannot make assume it is working properly (especially all methods from `Context`) as it is not properly initiated. Again the same strategy applies, use a separate `Context` object you pass to `changeLocale` to fix this.

Comment: Thank you Stephan, yes indeed, the same problem again. I don't really understand how to use context. I've been trying to figure it out, but as you can see, I'm not there yet. I'll try with the context object, thanks.

Comment: It's not working cos I don't understand how to pass the context around. I've instantiated the Prefs object in the field variables, and tried to use it in com.silifeform.android.Us.onOptionsItemSelected(), but I'm really just guessing at this stage. Sorry, I really do appreciate your patience and help with this :)

Comment: As a quick face just do the same as the last time: Add a parameter of type Context to `changeLocale` and pass this from the call in `onOptionsItemSelected()` and use that new parameter as first parameter in the `new Intent()` calls.

Comment: Thank you Stephan. It's not working yet but I have to stop coding now so I'll get back to it tomorrow. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Ok, when you say "if the Prefs class is not instantiated (and managed) by Android, you cannot make assume it is working properly (especially all methods from Context) as it is not properly initiated." how do I instantiate the class so Android manages it? I've tried putting public Prefs pob; in the field variables but same result.