# Android Null Pointer Exception for shared Preferences

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save a integer value in the Shared preferences and load it again when the application is restarted.

I have created a shared preferences in my main activity and trying to save integer value in a another Menu Listener class on menu item click. The Menu listener class is in a different package and the Menu Listener class extends the Main Activity.

But I am getting a Null pointer exception when I try to do that.

I have also gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991289/sharedpreferences-null-pointer-exception)!. But it doesn't seem to be helping me.

Here is my code:

Main Activity:

```
    protected SharedPreferences mPrefs;
protected SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
protected Context  main_activityclass_context; //EDIT
public static int count=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


     mPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("THEME", 0);
     mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    }
```

Menu Listener class:

```
    case  mainActivity.MENU_ITEM_THEME_DARK:
    {

        mainActivity.count=1;

        mPrefs =main_activityclass_context.getSharedPreferences("THEME", 0); //EDIT
        mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        mEditor.putInt("Theme_count", mainActivity.count).commit();


    break;
    }
```

I am getting a Null pointer exception on the lines in the Menu Listener :

```
       mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("THEME", 0);
        mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
```

My Logcat:

```
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258): java.lang.NullPointerException
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):  at               android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:153)
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):  at de.exb.ptpt.tablet.menu.TabletMenuListener.onMenuItemClick(TabletMenuListener.java:215)
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:144)
       08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
       08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:156)
       08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
       08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
      08-03 10:54:03.650: E/AndroidRuntime(31258):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone please help me?

Thank You.

Comment: Can you post the logcat output?

Comment: is your MenuListener class loading before the `mPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("THEME", 0);` ?

Comment: You have to post your Log-Cat displaying ERROR.

Comment: What is line 215 in TabletMenuListener.java?

Comment: @David Wasser 215 is mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("THEME", 0);

Comment: Are you testing this on a device or emulator? If device, what device?

Comment: Something very strange is going on here. Please post the whole TabletMenuListener class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33453494/5483879

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the good ways is, you create a helper class to declare, save and retrive preferences. You can refer following code sample:

```
public class PreferencesHelper {

private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private Editor editor;

public PreferencesHelper(Context context) {
this.sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);    
this.editor = sharedPreferences.edit(); }

public String GetPreferences(String key) {
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
}

public void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
editor.putString(key, value);    
editor.commit();  
}
}
```

In onCreate event of an activity, you can create of object of PreferencesHelper and get all saved preferences like:

```
Prefs = new PreferencesHelper(getApplicationContext());  

Prefs.GetPreferences("YOURARGUMENT");
```

and you can save the preferences like:

```
Prefs.SavePreferences(key, value);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Sndn You should use `GetPreferences` instead of `getPreferences`, or change the name of the method.

Answer (score 2):

Write This code outside the onCreate method.

```
mPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("THEME", 0);
     mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
```

mostly because of this it generating nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are using SharaedPrefrence in MenuListener Class:

In The Line ->

```
    getSharedPreferences("THEME", 0);
```

Here you  need the Context of MainActivity class

and you can use it as->

```
    main_activityclass_context.getSharedPreferences("THEME", 0);
```

Becoz in MenuListener class, You are not getting the context of MainActivity Class directly, you have to pass it to MenuListener Class.

Comment: hey, I tried it, but getting a null pointer pointer again. When debugging getting the main_activity_class as Null.

Comment: I mean the main_activityclass_context is Null

Comment: Post your **WHOLE** classes MainActivity and MenuListener, if you want to learn **Concept of Static and passing context**

Comment: But can you please tell if have done it right in the above edited code? I mean the creating of Context.

Comment: Um, this discussion thread is pointless. You can use any Context you want to call `getSharedPreferences()`. It can also be seen from the original stack trace that he has a Context and the call to `getSharedPreferences()` is executing. The NPE is happening **inside** the call to `getSharedPreferences()`.The problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Context as specified in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5991458/1105291

i.e. ur code will look something like

```
MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("THEME", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you get the shared preference value in App starting that time the preferenceactivity xml page not load so it show null pointer error. one time you go to the setting then it works properly .Null pointer error not show.