# Edit SharedPreferences with an Alarm

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, alarmmanager

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to update a value at a specific time, everyday, so that when the user opens the app, the value is current for the day.
The way I'm doing it is by calling an alarm which executes a method in my mainactivity.java that edits a value in the sharedPreferences. An example in code:

--------------------------MainActivity.java--------------------------

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 [...]
 int myVar=0;
 //Retrieving my saved data
     int sPSavedData=getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("DATA", 0);
     if(sPSavedData!=(0))
       {
        myVar=sPSavedData;
       }
  [...]
    }
//doing my thing
public void myCode(){
myVar=+1;
saveSP();
}
//saving data in Shared Preferences
public void saveSP(){
SharedPreferences.Editor sPEditor=getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit(); //<---I get an error here
sPEditor.putInt("DATA", myVar);
sPEditor.commit();
}
[...]
```

---

and then my Alarm.java file that has the receiver:

```
[...]
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        MainActivity code=new MainActivity();
        code.myCode();
     }
[...]
```

---

I'm getting an error when trying to do this

```
sPEditor=getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
```

and making sense of the logcat I understand it has something to do with not being able to retrieve the package name.

Is there any way to fix my error or any other way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust your code like this:

**saveData()**

```
public void saveData(Context context, int data){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = sharedPref.edit();
    spEditor.putInt("DATA", data);
    spEditor.commit();
}
```

**getData()**

```
public int getData(Context context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    int sPSavedData= sharedPref.getInt("DATA", 0);
    return sPSavedData;
}
```

**myCode()**

```
public void myCode(Context context){
    int sPSavedData = getData(context);
    if(sPSavedData != 0){
        saveData(context, sPSavedData++);
    }
}
```

**onReceive()**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    MainActivity code=new MainActivity();
    code.myCode(context);
}
```

Comment: this works, however, this seems to overwrite the my shared preferences with the default values. So for instance if in myVar i have stored the integer 50, the next time the app opens the value is reset.

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
SharedPreferences sPEditor = getSharedPreferences("yourfilename", 0);     
SharedPreferences.Editor sPEditor = sPEditor.edit();
```

it should solve your problem

Comment: So to clarify, "yourfilename" is just any name that I want to give it, or does it have to be an specific name? because I'm getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: it could be any name you prefer... by the way, you are getting null pointer as from where ? need more info to get your code running...

Comment: in the same line, SharedPreferences sPEditor = getSharedPreferences("yourfilename", 0);

Comment: try referring to these -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792593/android-null-pointer-exception-for-shared-preferences

Answer (score 0):

The `Context` is only created when opening the application, not when instantiating the class of your application/activity. If you want to have access to the context of your application you need to use a  `BroadcastReceiver` and follow the example here [Using alarmmanager and broadcastreceiver in android](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/) to schedule a periodic alarm.