# SharedPreferences returns a null even though it haves a default value

Tags: android, null, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I have my main activity which saves and load some data from the SharedPreferences... I've been able to do this until now.

These are my onCreate, onPause and OnResume methods.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle(R.string.title_activity_main);

    this.spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.geomObject);
    this.sbWidth = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.widthSB);
    this.sbDepth = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.depthSB);
    this.sbHeight = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.heightSB);
    this.widthProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.widthDisplay);
    this.depthProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.depthDisplay);
    this.heightProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heightDisplay);

    ...more code...
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadPrefs();
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    savePrefs();
}
```

And these are the method I do most of the work, so I can keep the onX methods clean:

```
private void savePrefs() {
    this.width = this.sbWidth.getProgress();
    this.depth = this.sbDepth.getProgress();
    this.height = this.sbHeight.getProgress();
    this.forma = this.spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

    getSharedPreferences("SEEKBARS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("width", width).commit();
    getSharedPreferences("SEEKBARS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("depth", depth).commit();
    getSharedPreferences("SEEKBARS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("height", height).commit();
    getSharedPreferences("SEEKBARS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("forma", forma).commit();
    getSharedPreferences("LOCKBARS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("lockbars", menuLock.isChecked()).commit();
}

private void loadPrefs() {
    int savedSpinner = getSharedPreferences("SEEKBARS", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("forma", SPINNER_DEFAULT);
    int savedWidth = getSharedPreferences("SEEKBARS", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("width", SEEKBAR_DEFAULT);
    int savedDepth = getSharedPreferences("SEEKBARS", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("depth", SEEKBAR_DEFAULT);
    int savedHeight = getSharedPreferences("SEEKBARS", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("height", SEEKBAR_DEFAULT);

    boolean savedLockFlag = getSharedPreferences("LOCKBARS", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("lockbars", false);

    this.spinner.setSelection(savedSpinner);
    this.sbWidth.setProgress(savedWidth);
    this.sbDepth.setProgress(savedDepth);
    this.sbHeight.setProgress(savedHeight);
//This is the line raising the exception Display:
        this.menuLock.setChecked(savedLockFlag); 


        this.widthProgress.setText(String.valueOf(savedWidth) + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.blocks));
        this.depthProgress.setText(String.valueOf(savedDepth) + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.blocks));
        this.heightProgress.setText(String.valueOf(savedHeight) + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.blocks));
    }
```

I don't see where is the error. I've been searching and I know that I can't call getSharedPreferences on onCreate, that's why I do it on onResume. What's wrong?

I also attach the logcat, just in case:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {es.nirvash.android.msg/es.nirvash.android.msg.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2109)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at es.nirvash.android.msg.MainActivity.loadPrefs(MainActivity.java:231)
    at es.nirvash.android.msg.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:147)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1154)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4539)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: "I don't see where is the error. I've been searching and I know that I can't call getSharedPreferences on onCreate, that's why I do it on onResume" Where did you hear this? That's wrong.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5991458/1569084 "getSharedPreferences() can only be called AFTER onCreate() has been called on an Activity."

Comment: use the debugger. to see what exactly is null.

Comment: your interpretation of this answer is wrong. getSharedPreferences() must be called only after onCreate is called by the system, which means you can call it during onCreate.

Comment: @Deses - I think they meant to say that you can only call it after super.onCreate(bundle) is called. You can certainly call it in the onCreate method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't your boolean, it's the variable `menuLock`. `boolean` (primitive type) cannot be `null`.

Find where `menuLock` is declared and make sure it has something to hold on to. That way, it will not be null when you use it. Of course, if it is a `View`, assign it something to hold on to in `onCreate()`, after `setContentView()`, since that's has the Activity layout and creating guaranteed.

Comment: Oh my god, that's it. Damn it! I forgot that menuLock is delcared somewhere else.

Comment: You're welcome :-) As I said in my answer, primitive types (char, int, boolean, double, float) can't be `null`. That's reserved for reference variables so always check those.

Comment: Yup, I know. sometimes I forgot to start the variables.